# Dynamically added HTML element after click event

Tags: vuejs2

I don't know how to add dynamic content in my Vue js 2 app. I'd like to add many div elements after clicking on a button. THis div should have input and after clicking on a Save button all input texts inside dynamically created divs should be sent to backend (so I use model inside my template).

```
<div v-if="!this.spinnerVisibleForCorrectiveActions">
                <div>
                    <table class="p-2 table-cell">
                        <tr class="font-weight-bold">
                            <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                <div class="mt-2 criterion">
                                    ID
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                <div class="mt-2 criterion">
                                    DZIAŁANIE
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                <div class="mt-2">
                                    SZCZEGÓŁY
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr v-for="(actions,index) in correctiveActions" :key="index">
                            <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                <span> {{actions.orderNumber}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                <span> {{actions.action}}</span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                <span> {{actions.recommendations}}</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <button class="addAction p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white w-100 bg-info btn btn-success">NAdd new action</button>
                    <br>
                </div>
```

How to add dynamically (multiple times) something like this and additionally to have the possibility to get all data from my dynamically created inputs after clicking on a button:

```
 <tr v-for="(actions,index) in correctiveActions" :key="index">
                                    <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                        <span> {{actions.orderNumber}}</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                        <span> {{actions.action}}</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="vue-good-table-col-200">
                                        <span> {{actions.recommendations}}</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer in my case is very simple - I have to only add an empty object to my correctiveActions array:

```
<button class="addAction p-2 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white w-100 bg-info btn btn-success" @click="addNewAction">Nowe
                        działanie
                    </button>
```

and next:

```
methods:{
 addNewAction() {
                this.correctiveActions.push
                ({
                    id: undefined,
                    incidentId: this.incidentId,
                    orderNumber: this.getNextOrderNumber(),
                    action: undefined,
                    recommendations: undefined
                });
            },
}
```